# Convert an Eclipse CDT project from Windows settings to Unix settings

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, unix

I have created a set of C++ projects under Eclipse CDT (Kepler - gcc - gdb), on my PC (Windows 7). Then, I uploaded them on GIT so as to make other people download them and test the contained algorithms.

However, some problems in the configurations are encountered. When you create a project under Windows, Eclipse binds the configurations for **that specific OS** into the project. Thus, if the project is imported on another platform (e.g., OS X), people compiling it will not be able to execute it, since in the project specification it is written that the executable will be a `.exe`, and so forth and so on for all the other configurations for Windows.

I would like to know whether there exists a **simple** but **effective** way of converting the project from a "Windows format" to a "Unix format" (and viceversa). I am requiring it to be simple, since the people that will download the projects are not skilled and I cannot require them to perform complicated passages in order to set up the environment.

Thanks in advance,

Eleanore.